# log4net - TraceListener & TraceAppender - mixing two methods of logging

Tags: logging, log4net, trace

In our system we use simultaneously both Trace.Write() (old method) and logging via log4net.

I want to unify those methods. I've added custom listener called Log4NetTraceListener, which handle messages from Trace and put them into log file. Simplified code:

```
public class Log4NetTraceListener : System.Diagnostics.TraceListener
{
public override void Write(string message)
{
            _log.Debug(message);
}
```

It works fine., but what I want to do also is logging to output window of Visual Studio even for regular log4net methods.

My first idea was to add TraceAppender to log4net configuration. It would work fine, but in engagement with the listener it causes a endless loop.

Is there any "clean" way to handle such problem? Maybe some filtering of listener or appender?

Comment: Can't you just add a DebugAppender to the log4net config?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the `Trace.Write()` calls go through the `Log4NetTraceListener` class and that the rest of your log4net logging does not (i.e. it's just normal `.Debug()`, `.Error()` calls) then you can configure your logging hierarchy so that the `Trace.Write()` calls do not end up calling the TraceAppender. e.g.

```xml
<log4net>
  <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
  </root>
  <logger name="Log4NetTraceListener">
    <level value="OFF" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

This makes the assumption that the `_log` field in `Log4NetTraceListener` was given a logger name of Log4NetTraceListener.

Alternatively if you use the `DebugAppender` instead of `TraceAppender`, it will, *whilst debugging*, output to the Visual Studio Output window.